# Modx добавление спарсеных новостей в бд

Tags: php, sql, modx, revo

Товарищи, как реализовать добавление спарсеных данных в бд и создавались уже готовые дочерние ресуры с этими данными в полях?
Слышал что плагин ImportX может помочь, только я пока не разобрался как именно)
Или как правильно задать такой вопрос гуглу?

UPD: ImportX судя по всему не поможет, так как мне нужно загружать новости, переодически запуская скрипт парсера по крону.

Answer (score 0):

Да, ImportX поможет. Также можно написать собственный сниппет по разбору данных(например, из csv формата) и используя MODX XPDO создавать новые ресурсы.
Также есть платный компонент https://modstore.pro/packages/import-and-export/msimportexport

Comment: Привет, я добавил уточнение. Дело в том что мне нужно запускать парсер по крону, пока не разобрался как это реализовать.

Comment: Реализовать парсер? или запуск по крону? для второго поможет компонент CronManager

Comment: Парсер сделан, мне же нужно теперь заносить эту инфу в бд, создавать ресурсы, переназначить данные. Нашел вот такую статью https://webinmind.ru/modx/solutions/working-with-resources/editing-resources-through-the-processor
Тут немного срывают покровы